# rails ajax js error in success area

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have such js:

```
function get_models(manufacturer_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/cars/get_models/"+manufacturer_id,    
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
    success: function(text) {
      $("#model-select").html(text);
    }
    error: function(){
      //alert('Ошибка javascript');
      $.ajax(this);
    }
  });
}
```

but i get error on line success: function(text) {,  and if i change it to success: function(data) or success: function()  i still get error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "   but why? i didn't imagine why )

Comment: you're missing a comma after `dataType: 'html'` and after closing `}` of success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed `,` after dataType and success.

change

```
    dataType: "html"
    success: function(text) {
     $("#model-select").html(text);
    }
```

to

```
 dataType: "html",
 success: function(text) {
     $("#model-select").html(text);
 },
```

Comment: since you've added this as an answer, you might as well include the other issue, missing comma after `}` of success function.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax accept attributes in hash, so you should put values in hash and all the values should be separate with ',' .

you did not put , after

```
dataType: "html" like dataType: "html",

and 

suceess block
    success: function(text) {
        $("#model-select").html(text);
    },



function get_models(manufacturer_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cars/get_models/"+manufacturer_id,    
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(text) {
            $("#model-select").html(text);
        },
        error: function(){
            $.ajax(this);
        }
    });
}
```